Gluability in the Proj Construction
I am stuck with proving the isomorphism
$(S_{(f)})_{g^{\deg f}/f^{\deg g}} \cong S_{(g)}$ when its given that $D_+(g) \subset D_+(f)$.
I am following the stack notes and the exact result can be found in this link:
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M3
I will sincerely appreciate any help that I may receive. Thanks in advance!
I could show that the natural map is injective. I am stuck with the surjectivity part.

What have you tried, how far have you gotten in your attempt, and where specifically are you stuck? Please add these details to your post in an [edit].

Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have edited and pointed out where I am stuck. Would you rather want me to write down my proof of the fact that this map is injective?
